# What happens if i remove Mongo server from a Sitecore 8 site

Tags: xdb, mongodb

A client wants to cut down on servers and since they do not use the Experience Platform I am wondering if i could just eliminate the Mongo server. There is as of now absolutely no data in the Mongo server. What settings do i need to change to not get flooded with errors when i turn it off? Is this even adviceble?

Comment: You need to disable xDB. See https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/experience_management/configuring/disabling_xdb_and_the_xdb_tracker

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several things which doesn't work properly anymore. You can disable it in the config. Go to `/App_Config/Include/Sitecore.Analytics.config` and set `Analytics.Enabled` to `false`:

```xml
<setting name="Analytics.Enabled" value="false" />
```

You also need to comment out all MongoDB connection stings:

```xml
<add name="analytics" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/analytics" />
<add name="tracking.live" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/tracking_live" />
<add name="tracking.history" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/tracking_history" />
<add name="tracking.contact" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/tracking_contact" />
<add name="reporting" connectionString="user id=user;password=password;Data Source=(server);Database=Sitecore_Analytics" />
```

‌
Source (with additional information): https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/296641

With Sitecore 8.1 there is a new mode called *CMS-only mode*. You find all information about this here:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/experience_management/experience_management_an_overview

Comment: Here is the sitecore documentation link https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/296641

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can disable xDB.

You need to add a patch file `Xdb.Enabled` and `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` set to false:

```
<setting name="Xdb.Enabled">
    <patch:attribute name="value">false</patch:attribute>
</setting>
<setting name="Xdb.Tracking.Enabled">
    <patch:attribute name="value">false</patch:attribute>
</setting>
```

Make sure you also remove mongo connection strings.

Comment: Please note this is an 8.1 setting only. Does not apply to 8.0

Comment: Thanks @RichardSeal . You're absolutely right. I've been working with Sitecore 8.1+ for so long that I already forgot it was different in 8.0 ;)